# How can I retrieve data from a real-time map online?

Tags: c#, web, html-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve data from a real-time map of bus routes in Washington State for a school project in C# (specifically the vehicles themselves, and their status/location). I've linked the website I'm getting the data from below. I've inspected the HTML on the page, but can't find anything about a data source. I've tried setting it up as a simple WebClient and using the .DownloadString method to retrieve data in the hopes that that might provide hints too, but I can't seem to pull anything. Could anyone help me figure out how to retrieve data on the bus routes?

http://tripplanner.kingcounty.gov/hiwire?.a=iRealTimeDisplay

Comment: I doubt they expose that data for you to consume.

Comment: The data is directly available to the public. It's real time bus locations so as to plan your arrivals and departures accordingly. Access to the data isn't the issue. Parsing it is.